# AD value userAccountControl not changed

Tags: active-directory

When I set the flag "User cannot change password" in the user settings of my active directory I would expect the value userAccountControl to change its value. But it doesn't.
I start with that:

```
userAccountControl = 0x200 => NORMAL_ACCOUNT
```

If I set the flag "User cannot change password" I would expect this:

```
userAccountControl = 0x240 => NORMAL_ACCOUNT and PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE
```

But it is still the old value.
 
If I set the flag "Password never expires" then userAccountControl changes. But why isn't that working with "User cannot change password"?

Comment: What makes you think that the useraccountcontrol attribute reflects password permissions?

Comment: @JimB: this site indicates that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: ahh, ok you must have missed the line on update frequency that said this attribute was changed on policy change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That checkbox doesn't modify the `userAccountControl` attribute (on the 2008 DC that I checked on); instead, it adds Deny ACEs against the Change Password right for `SELF` and `Everyone`.

[image: changepwd]